# How does Swift store arrays of structs?

Tags: swift

Could you explain to a C programmer precisely what happens under the hood when you do something along these lines in Swift:

```
struct X { var a: Int32; var b: Int32 }
class Y { var a: Int32; var b: Int32 }
var x1 = X[](count: 1000)
let x2 = X[](count: 1000)
var y1 = Y[](count: 1000)
let y2 = Y[](count: 1000)
```

In particular, exactly what is the memory layout? What is allocated from the stack, and what is allocated from the heap? How many separate memory blocks do we allocate here?

My *guess* is that something along these lines happens:

- x1 and x2 are pointers to a contiguous memory block that contains the size of the array (1000), followed by 2000 integers (storing x1[0].a, x1[0].b, x1[1].a, ... in this order); the memory block is allocated from the heap.
- y1 and y2 are pointers to a contiguous memory block that contains the size of the array (1000), followed by 1000 pointers (storing a reference to objects y1[0], y1[1], ...); each of these points to a separate memory block that represents an instance of object Y, and these memory blocks contain reference counters + fields a and b; each object Y is separately allocated from the heap.

Is this anywhere near to what actually happens in Apple's current implementation of Swift?

In the resulting machine code, is there any difference between how x1 and x2 are stored or accessed? What about between y1 and y2?

Comment: We don't know, Apple didn't release enough information about the internals yet.

Comment: @Sulthan: People can compile Swift code, run it in a debugger, disassemble, inspect the memory layout, etc. In principle, it should be possible to answer this question, at least for those people who have access to Xcode 6 beta.

Comment: However, consider that arrays have copy-on-write behaviour, so they are probably only small wrappers around a pointer to the real array somewhere on the heap. The wrapper (the actual array) could be allocated on the stack (it's a `struct`). Constant (`let`) arrays cannot change size while mutable (`var`) can. That will probably make some difference in the memory layout. Mutable arrays could actually use a `NSMutableArray` instance internally.

Comment: That depends on compiler optimization, it may even splat the array into several variables, or remove part of them... @Sulthan arrays have copy-on-extension behaviour, not copy-on-write. If you replace an existing element in an array without changing its length, the array is not copied.

Answer (score 3):

It is unspecified. You can go and disassemble the compiled code, but that's just what it **currently** does, and it may change at any time with no notice.

I do understand the desire of a C programmer to try to figure out what happens under the hood. But you really really should not care at all. It's like when C came out and programmers, used to work in assembly, wanted to know exactly at what physical memory address a struct was stored or which local variables were being mapped to CPU registers and which to the stack frame. In very early compilers that was something you could actually know, but you really should not care. Not even if you think it makes a difference.

Comment: Without knowing the memory layout it is very difficult to reason about  memory usage (e.g., "how large data sets can I process in 8 GB of RAM"), memory locality, and cache efficiency (e.g., "does a linear scan of the array correspond to a linear scan of memory").

Comment: Sure. 

Without knowing exactly which local variables are registers and which are on the stack it's very hard to reason about efficiency. Which is why the old time ASM programmers wanted to know it.

Also without knowing exactly at which address a certain structure is stored, it's hard to know if you can optimize space by only saving the low bits of it's address instead of a full pointer. And that impacts how large a memory footprint you have.

Comment: A Swift array is a value type which is copied, but it has content-sharing with copy-on-size-changes semantics. How much memory it allocates is unknown. In fact it's also unknown in C (do you really think that `malloc(x)` consumes exactly `x` bytes? If so you are deluded. It consumes __at least__ `x` bytes, but how many exactly depends on the implementation).

Comment: What you say about malloc is one of the reasons why it is important to know whether an array of n objects is allocated as a single memory block or as n+1 memory blocks. In the former case, the overhead related to memory management is negligible for a large n; in the latter case it becomes significant. This is very easy to observe e.g. in Java in which every object is allocated from a heap, and there is some memory management overhead associated with each object (compare the equivalents of "struct of arrays of ints" vs. "array of structs of ints" in Java).

Comment: The arrays are dynamic therefore, in general, storage for the array content must be allocated on the heap. It's reasonable to assume it's contiguous storage (for O(1) access). Beyond that you do not know and should not know. Small arrays may be handled differently than large ones. What really happens may depend on how many arrays are sharing the data. Optimizations may allocate stuff on the stack, or even in registers. The heap may be managed differently than it is in C (that is it may be a separate heap not managed with `malloc`). What happens may change when you upgrade the OS.

Comment: @AnalogFile, we **should** care about memory structure, when pass vertex data to OpenGL, for example.

Comment: @kelin Yes and no. If you use a Swift API to access OpenGL, the implementation of that API takes care of it. If you directly access OpenGL C routines then the parameters will be UnsafePointers and you have two options: manipulate the buffers referred to by those UnsafePointers directly or pass instances of an Array as arguments, in which case Swift takes care to convert them to a contiguous "C array" behind the scene.

Comment: If you have to worry about those things then the compiler, language and frameworks have failed.